# Is it expensive to parse an ExpressionTree?

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I am currently reading through the MSDN, [**Walkthrough: Creating an IQueryable LInQ Provider**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx) and there is a lot of use of the `ExpressionVisitor`.

It makes me wonder, is it an expensive operation to use this?

**Is it as expensive as Reflection?**

Comment: Those two do completely different things, so I think you can't compare them. You could compare specific use of reflection with specific use of `ExpressionVisitor`, but you don't need to ask a question for that, you can measure that yourself.

Comment: In the past, I've implemented a simple visitor based on the article you linked. Visiting the nodes of the tree at runtime to do something useful (e.g. create a SQL statement) has a measurable and fairly linear performance impact (the more complex the expression, the longer it takes to visit). Of course, whether or not it matters depends on the needs of your application.

Answer (score 1):

No, it should be quite cheap to traverse an expression tree with an `ExpressionVisitor`.

There is no run-time cost at all needed to parse the expression tree. The compiler does all the work of turning an Expression into an object tree *at compile time*. There isn't even much run-time reflection going on when the objects in question are created in memory. When you see a method call like:

```
SomeMethod(Foo x => x.Property);
```

and SomeMethod's argument is `Expression` typed, then the compiler converts the code into IL which acts like you had written something like this:

```
SomeMethod(new MemberExpression {
  Expression = new ParameterExpression("x", typeof(Foo)),
  Member = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Property")
});
```

You can look at the generated IL for the full details, or see the worked example in [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).
There is some reflection involved (for example `MemberExpressions` hold a `PropertyInfo` reference), but it is all quite fast.

If you have an app you are worried about, you should profile it (e.g. recent versions of Visual Studio have a built in performance profiler) and see which specific parts are slow.

Comment: thank you for answering, but I do not think that your answer matches my question. First of all, you seem confused about what IL is. Your example is using Expressions, not IL. Secondly, you did not mention walking the Expression tree with the ExpressionVisitor at all. Both of which do not speak well to your credibility on the subject. I think you may have stopped reading my question with the Title and have given me your best guess.

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens I don't think Rich is confused about IL. When converting a lambda to expression, the compiler does emit IL (what else?). The difference is, it's not IL that represents the lambda, it's IL that creates expression that represents the lambda.

Comment: @svick, why are we even talking about IL? It has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Stu, that is inaccurate; only compiled expressions will emit IL. Until they are compiled, the are just objects. When parsing an expression tree, you are essentially traversing a semi-complicated object tree. IL is as much a fit for this conversation as it would be if I were asking about XML or OData.

Comment: When the C# compiler encounters "Expression" types, it generates very different IL for the expression than it would otherwise do. It is not possible to explain the performance aspects of Expressions without discussing the generated IL, which is why I brought it up. I can see that I have not clarified things for you though :-)  Perhaps read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx  @svick's comment is correct. My point was that, when dealing with expression trees, there is little or no actual run-time reflection involved, so it should be faster.

Comment: @rich, Thank you for responding and thank you for cleaning up the answer. It is looking much better. It still does not demonstrate a thorough understanding of Expression Tree Traversal. If you would like to read up on the subject, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx, and of course the original article mentioned in this question, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx . I also suggest you do some searches on Google for ExpressionVisitor. I apologize if my comments seem abrasive. They are meant only to be honest.